# Generics and casting - cannot cast inherited class to base class

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I know this is old, yet I am still not very good with understanding those problems. Can anyone tell me why the following does not work (throws a `runtime` exception about casting)?

```
public abstract class EntityBase { }
public class MyEntity : EntityBase { }

public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> where T : EntityBase { }
public class MyEntityRepository : RepositoryBase<MyEntity> { }
```

And now the casting line:

```
MyEntityRepository myEntityRepo = GetMyEntityRepo(); // whatever
RepositoryBase<EntityBase> baseRepo = (RepositoryBase<EntityBase>)myEntityRepo;
```

So, can anyone explain how is this invalid? And, I you are not in the mood to explain - is there a line of code I can use to actually do this cast?

Comment: Check out the [C# Covariance and Contravariance FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers. To make it short - I now resolved this problem with a base interface (RepositoryBase<T> : IRepository). Turns out I just need to execute the functions on the instance I get and let the class itself handle other things.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`RepositoryBase<EntityBase>` is *not* a base class of `MyEntityRepository`. You're looking for *generic variance* which exists in C# to a limited extent, but wouldn't apply here.

Suppose your `RepositoryBase<T>` class had a method like this:

```
void Add(T entity) { ... }
```

Now consider:

```
MyEntityRepository myEntityRepo = GetMyEntityRepo(); // whatever
RepositoryBase<EntityBase> baseRepo = (RepositoryBase<EntityBase>)myEntityRepo; 
baseRepo.Add(new OtherEntity(...));
```

Now you've added a different kind of entity to a `MyEntityRepository`... and that can't be right.

Basically, generic variance is only safe in certain situations. In particular generic *covariance* (which is what you're describing here) is only safe when you only ever get values "out" of the API; generic *contravariance* (which works the other way round) is only safe when you only ever put values "into" the API (e.g. a general comparison which can compare any two shapes by area can be considered as a comparison of squares).

In C# 4 this is available for generic interfaces and generic delegates, not classes - and only with reference types. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx) for further information, read <plug>read [C# in Depth, 2nd edition](http://manning.com/skeet2), chapter 13</plug> or Eric Lippert's [blog series](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/) on the topic. Also, I gave a one hour talk about this at NDC in July 2010 - the video is available [here](https://vimeo.com/17599365).

Comment: Thanks Jon, both for the explanation and the link to very interesting material. I will definitely consider reading the book and looking at the video.

Comment: It seems that the link to your video has broken.

Comment: @ZacharyBurns: Fixed, thanks. I'm somewhat astonished it's still available :)

Answer (score 23):

Whenever someone asks this question, I try to take their example and translate it to something using more well-known classes that is obviously illegal (this is what [Jon Skeet has done in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528821/generics-and-casting-cannot-cast-inherited-class-to-base-class/3528845#3528845); but I'm taking it a step further by performing this translation).

Let's replace `MyEntityRepository` with `MyStringList`, like this:

```
class MyStringList : List<string> { }
```

Now, you seem to want `MyEntityRepository` to be castable to `RepositoryBase<EntityBase>`, the reasoning being that this ought to be possible since `MyEntity` derives from `EntityBase`.

But `string` derives from `object`, doesn't it? So by this logic we should be able to cast a `MyStringList` to a `List<object>`.

Let's see what can happen if we allow that...

```
var strings = new MyStringList();
strings.Add("Hello");
strings.Add("Goodbye");

var objects = (List<object>)strings;
objects.Add(new Random());

foreach (string s in strings)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Length of string: {0}", s.Length);
}
```

Uh-oh. Suddenly we're enumerating over a `List<string>` and we come upon a `Random` object. That's not good.

Hopefully this makes the issue a bit easier to understand.

Comment: I've started going one step further in examples - I used to use string and object, but at Eric Lippert's suggestion I've started using real world objects... Fruit/Apple/Banana works well in terms of "you can't add an apple to a bunch of bananas".

Answer (score 10):

This requires covariance or contravariance, whose support is limited in .Net, and cannot be used on abstract classes. You can use variance on interfaces though, so a possible solution to your problem is to create an IRepository which you use in place of the abstract class.

```
    public interface IRepository<out T> where T : EntityBase { //or "in" depending on the items.
    }
    public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepository<T> where T : EntityBase {
    }
    public class MyEntityRepository : RepositoryBase<MyEntity> {
    }

    ...

    IRepository<EntityBase> baseRepo = (IRepository<EntityBase>)myEntityRepo;
```