# Please help me understand polymorphism when using generics in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, asp.net-mvc-2, nested-generics

I am having a problem understanding how polymorphism works when using generics. As an example, I have defined the following program:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    void MyMethod();
}

public class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
    }
}

public class MyContainer<T> where T : IMyInterface
{
    public IList<T> Contents;
}
```

I can then do this, which works just fine:

```
MyContainer<MyClass> container = new MyContainer<MyClass>();
container.Contents.Add(new MyClass());
```

I have many classes that implement MyInterface. I would like to write a method that can accept all MyContainer objects:

```
public void CallAllMethodsInContainer(MyContainer<IMyInterface> container)
{
    foreach (IMyInterface myClass in container.Contents)
    {
        myClass.MyMethod();
    }
}
```

Now, I'd like to call this method.

```
MyContainer<MyClass> container = new MyContainer<MyClass>();
container.Contents.Add(new MyClass());
this.CallAllMethodsInContainer(container);
```

That didn't work. Surely, because MyClass implements IMyInterface, I should be able to just cast it?

```
MyContainer<IMyInterface> newContainer = (MyContainer<IMyInterface>)container;
```

That didn't work either. I can definitely cast a normal MyClass to IMyInterface:

```
MyClass newClass = new MyClass();
IMyInterface myInterface = (IMyInterface)newClass;
```

So, at least I haven't completely misunderstood that. I am unsure exactly how I am to write a method that accepts a generic collection of classes that conform to the same interface.

I have a plan to completely hack around this problem if need be, but I would really prefer to do it properly.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is where people trot out scary words like covariance and contravariance.

Comment: @Greg: On the plus side, I feel like my *own* understanding of these concepts has really been fleshed out recently due to the plethora of questions like this that have been popping up!

Comment: The concepts are good, but the names are scary. :)

Comment: @Greg: Agreed. I propose we change them to [gobbling and spewing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662369/covariance-and-contravariance-real-world-example/2662396#2662396).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: In all cases, you will have to initialize the `Contents` field to a concrete  object that implements `IList<?>`

When you keep the generic constraint, you can do:

```
public IList<T> Contents = new List<T>();
```

When you don't, you can do:

```
public IList<MyInterface> Contents = new List<MyInterface>();
```

**Method 1:**

Change the method to:

```
public void CallAllMethodsInContainer<T>(MyContainer<T> container) where T : IMyInterface
{
    foreach (T myClass in container.Contents)
    {
        myClass.MyMethod();
    }
}
```

and the snippet to:

```
MyContainer<MyClass> container = new MyContainer<MyClass>();
container.Contents.Add(new MyClass());
this.CallAllMethodsInContainer(container);
```

**Method 2:**

Alternatively, move the `CallAllMethodsInContainer` method to the `MyContainer<T>` class like this:

```
public void CallAllMyMethodsInContents()
    {
        foreach (T myClass in Contents)
        {
            myClass.MyMethod();
        }
    }
```

and change the snippet to:

```
MyContainer<MyClass> container = new MyContainer<MyClass>();
container.Contents.Add(new MyClass());
container.CallAllMyMethodsInContents();
```

**Method 3:**

EDIT: Yet another alternative is to remove the generic constraint from the `MyContainer` class like this:

```
public class MyContainer
{
    public IList<MyInterface> Contents;
}
```

and to change the method signature to

```
  public void CallAllMethodsInContainer(MyContainer container)
```

Then the snippet should work as:

```
MyContainer container = new MyContainer();
container.Contents.Add(new MyClass());
this.CallAllMethodsInContainer(container);
```

Note that with this alternative, the container's `Contents` list will accept any combination of objects that implement `MyInterface`.

Answer (score 3):

Wow, this question's been coming up a lot lately.

Short answer: No, this isn't possible. Here's what **is** possible:

```
public void CallAllMethodsInContainer<T>(MyContainer<T> container) where T : IMyInterface
{
    foreach (IMyInterface myClass in container.Contents)
    {
        myClass.MyMethod();
    }
}
```

And here's why what you tried **isn't** possible (taken from [this recent answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528821/generics-and-casting-cannot-cast-inherited-class-to-base-class/3528897#352889723));)):

Consider the `List<T>` type. Say you have a `List<string>` and a `List<object>`. string derives from object, but it does not follow that `List<string>` derives from `List<object>`; if it did, then you could have code like this:

```
var strings = new List<string>();

// If this cast were possible...
var objects = (List<object>)strings;

// ...crap! then you could add a DateTime to a List<string>!
objects.Add(new DateTime(2010, 8, 23));23));
```

The above code illustrates what it means to be (and not to be) a [**covariant type**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx). Note that casting a type `T<D>` to another type `T<B>` where `D` derives from `B` is possible (in .NET 4.0) if `T` is *covariant*; a generic type is covariant if its generic type argument only ever appears in the form of output -- i.e., read-only properties and function return values.

Think of it this way: if some type `T<B>` always *supplies a `B`*, then one that always supplies a `D` (`T<D>`) will be able to operate as a `T<B>` since all `D`s are `B`s.

Incidentally, a type is *contravariant* if its generic type parameter only ever appears in the form of input -- i.e., method parameters. If a type `T<B>` is contravariant then it can be cast to a `T<D>`, as strange as that may seem.

Think of it this way: if some type `T<B>` always *requires a `B`*, then it can step in for one that always requires a `D` since, again, all `D`s are `B`s.

Your `MyContainer` class is neither covariant nor contravariant because its type parameter appears in both contexts -- as input (via `Contents.Add`) and as output (via the `Contents` property itself).

Answer (score 1):

this is problem of covariance

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx

you can't cast `MyContainer<MyClass>` to `MyContainer<IMyInterface>` because then you could do things like `Contents.Add(new AnotherClassThatImplementsIMyInterface())`