# Convert MyClass<TDescendent> to MyClass<TAncestor>

Tags: c#, generics

If I have a root interface

```
public interface IEntity {}
```

And a derived interface, and classes:

```
public interface IFruit : IEntity {}
public class Apple : IFruit {}
public class Orange: IFruit {}
```

And, irrelevant, but perhaps others that don't implement `IFruit`:

```
public class Computer : IEntity {}
```

And a generic class that uses all this:

```
public class PurchasedItem<T> where T : IFruit 
{
    public int Qty{get;set;}
    public T Item{get;set;}
}
```

How can I declare a list that contains `PurchasedItem<IFruit>` and work with it?
If I do this:

```
var list = new List<PurchasedItem<IFruit>>();
list.Add(new PurchasedItem<Apple>());
```

...then I get an error

`Cannot convert from PurchasedItem<Apple> to PurchasedItem<IFruit>`

Comment: That *is* how you declare a list that contains `PurchasedItem<IFruit>` and work with it. Which means you can't store a `PurchasedItem<Apple>` in it, since that is not a `PurchasedItem<IFruit>`. This has been asked many times before, I'll see if I can find a good question with detailed answer.

Comment: did you try casting to base type ? , new  PurchasedItem<Apple>()).Cast<IFruit>

Comment: @Shachaf.Gortler That doesn't apply here, but wouldn't be useful even if it did apply.

Comment: @Shachaf.Gortler `.Cast` is an extension method of `IEnumerable`. Casting is not the issue. The problem is that it is a list of `PurchasedItem<IFruit>` not `PurchasedItem<Apple>`.

Comment: I guess I'm having trouble understanding why `PurchasedItem<IFruit>` isn't the same as `PurchasedItem<anything that implements IFruit>`.

Comment: The `Apple` implements `IFruit` but `PurchasedItem<Apple>` doesn't implement `PurchasedItem<IFruit>`. You would need a parent class that `PurchasedItem` could inherit from.

Comment: I *think* [Generics and casting - cannot cast inherited class to base class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3528821) is a good dupe target (despite the base class / implemented interface difference), but I'll let someone else review and make the call.

Comment: @Geoff For your particular case, consider `list.Add(new PurchasedItem<Apple>()); list[0].Item = new Orange();`. Since `list[0]` has type `PurchasedItem<IFruit>`, which has an `IFruit Item` property with an accessible setter, the second statement cannot be invalid. The two statements combined clearly must be invalid: `PurchasedItem<Apple>`'s `Item` property does not accept `Orange` values. Therefore, the first statement must be invalid.

Comment: @hvd Ok, I think I understand your point - the list implies a wider `Item` type than the instance does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use covariance if you create and work with an interface for `PurchaseItem<T>`

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IFruit : IEntity
{
}

public class Apple : IFruit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IPurchaseItem<out T> where T : IFruit
{
    int Qty { get; set; }
    T Item { get; } // can't have setter here
}

public class PurchaseItem<T> : IPurchaseItem<T>
    where T : IFruit
{
    public int Qty { get; set; }
    public T Item { get; set; } // setter here no problem
}


class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {
        var applePurchaseItem = new PurchaseItem<Apple>();

        var fruitPurchaseItems = new List<IPurchaseItem<IFruit>>();

        fruitPurchaseItems.Add( applePurchaseItem );
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  For `T Item` in `IPurchaseItem`, I get that "the type parameter T must be invariantly valid..."

Comment: You can't have a setter on the property in the `IPurchaseItem<T>` interface, only on the concrete implementation (note the `T Item { get; }`)

Comment: @Moho Thanks for this - it helps a lot, and also prompted me to do a lot of reading!

Answer (score 2):

It all comes down to the design of the class tree. For example, see the code below:

```
public interface IEntity {}

public interface IFruit : IEntity {}

public class PurchasedItem
{
    public int Qty { get; set; }
}

public class Apple : PurchasedItem, IFruit {}
public class Orange: PurchasedItem, IFruit {}

var list = new List<PurchasedItem>();
```

Comment: This solves the compilation error, but it doesn't solve the issue of being able to access an `IFruit` cleanly from the list.

Comment: John H, nothing stops you from doing this: var list = new List<IFruit>();

Comment: I don't want to subclass `PurchasedItem` -> `Apple` because `Apple` is a business object that has other uses, I don't want to tangle them up with `PurchasedItem` - and already has an ancestor.