# Instantiating and casting the Class which extends the generic abstract class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oop, generics

I have an abstract class which has generic

```
public abstract class BaseService<T>
{
public abstract void Read(T param);
}
```

and I have few other classes which is extending this abstract class

```
public class ServiceOne : BaseService<DTOParam>
{
public override void Read(DTOParam param)
{
//Do something with this DTOParam
}
}

//Other class
public class ServiceTwo : BaseService<DTOParamtwo>
{
public override void Read(DTOParamtwo param)
{
//Do something with this DTOParamtwo
}
}
```

I have been trying to Instantiate these class like

```
BaseService<T> bs = new ServiceOne();
```

which is throwing and error as

```
Cannot implicitly convert type ServiceOne to BaseService<T>
```

If you remove the generic it is working fine, What I am missing here? Or is the above approach not possible at all.

Comment: For clarification, what is the class and method that contain the method that won't compile? I can make a good guess as to what's going on but I have to see what the code is to show where/how to change it.

Comment: If you strictly need to get that line of code to compile than Scott Hannen's answer get you 95% there, just make the method generic with `where T: BaseService<DTOParam>`... Otherwise reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817300/convert-listderivedclass-to-listbaseclass and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528821/generics-and-casting-cannot-cast-inherited-class-to-base-class to get some more information about what generics are and aren't.

Comment: Side note: please avoid adding history inline into the post. If one wants to see what was edited they can just check edit history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A generic class is a semantic trick, when you instantiate or create a derived from a generic class the compiler creates a different class for each type. Thus, there's no way to cast a derived class which implements a concrete type to a typeless base.

You have two options, cast to the concrete generic type or create an underliying common base (i think the second option is what you really want). To create a common base, in your implementation you would also create on the base a function which accepts an Object as parameter and that function would call to the real generic implementation (see the example below).

Cast to concrete type:

```
BaseService<DTOParam> bs =  new ServiceOne();
```

Create a common base:

```
public abstract class BaseService
{
    public abstract void Read(object parm);
}

public abstract class GenericBaseService<T> : BaseService
{
    public override void Read(object parm)
    {
        Read((T)parm);
    }

    public abstract void Read(T parm);
}

public class ServiceOne : GenericBaseService<DTOParam>
{
    public override void Read(DTOParam param)
    {
        //Do something with this DTOParam
    }
}

//Now you can do:
BaseService srv = new ServiceOne();
srv.Read(dataOnject);
```

Answer (score 1):

The case sensitivity might be an issue. If you have two classes declared, `Baseservice<T>` and `BaseService<T>` then you could be using the wrong type.

The problem is likely in the method declaration that contains the statement.

For example, this won't work:

```
public static BaseService<T> GetService<T>()
{
    BaseService<T> returnValue = new ServiceOne();
    return returnValue;
}
```

because `T` could be any type, so you can't assign `ServiceOne`, which is a `BaseService<DTOParam>`, to `BaseService<T>`. What if `T` is `int` or some other type? You can't assign `BaseService<DTOParam>` to `BaseService<ItMightBeAnything>`.

This, on the other hand, works:

```
public static BaseService<DTOParam> GetService()
{
    BaseService<DTOParam> returnValue = new ServiceOne();
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: You can even get OP's code to compile with `public static BaseService<T> GetService<T>() where T : BaseService<DTOParam>` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can not create abject and cast at generic type T:

```
Baseservice bs = new ServiceOne();
```

should be:

```
ServiceOne bs = new ServiceOne();
```

You can later cast bs to base class if you need, but you need and generic type:

```
Baseservice bs1 = (BaseService<DTOParam>)bs;
```

Or if you insist on casting on creating instance should be:

```
Baseservice<DTOParam> bs =  new ServiceOne();
```

Comment: The non-generic `Baseservice` isn't defined anywhere. `Baseservice<T>` is a generic class so you can't use it without specifying the generic type.

Answer (score -2):

You have a typo in your code `BaseService` should be `Baseservice`:

```
public class ServiceOne : Baseservice<DTOParam>
{
    public override void Read(DTOParam param)
    {
        //Do something with this DTOParam
    }
}
```

Comment: This should have been a comment.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't know that.