# Generic type parameter is an class that implements an interface

Tags: c#, generics

Suppose we have a class that implements an interface

`class MyParaClass : IMyParaInterface`

And another class named MyObject which takes generic T

`class MyObject<T> where T: IMyParaInterface`

Now I have a method that accepts this parameter

`Print(MyObject<IMyParaInterface> parameter)`

When I get an object which type is `MyObject<MyParaClass>`, and try to pass this to `Print` method,Build fails because it can not convert `MyObject<MyParaClass>` to `MyObject<IMyParaInterface>`

I thought there should be not an issue as `MyParaClass` implements `IMyParaInterface`.How to solve this or get around?

Comment: @E_net4 thanks for reminding, it is c#

Comment: What exact error does the compiler throw?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generics and casting - cannot cast inherited class to base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528821/generics-and-casting-cannot-cast-inherited-class-to-base-class). This variation uses an interface rather than a base class, but the underlying issue is the same.

Answer (score 2):

You should define your Print method as a template method:

```
void Print<T>(MyObject<T> parameter) where T : IMyParaInterface {}
```

Which means, that the method would take any MyObject<> instance, whose type argument  implements your IMyParaInterface interface.

The problem with your original Print() code is, that it only accepts MyObject< IMyParaInterface > as input. Note, that MyObject< MyParaClass > is not instance of type MyObject< IMyParaInterface >.

There is **another solution**, where you can use .net's Covariance / contravariance features, by defining an interface for your object, where the type parameter will be marked as covariant (*out* T).

```
public interface IMyObject<out T> where T: IMyParaInterface {}

public class MyObject<T> : IMyObject<T> where T: IMyParaInterface {}


public static void Print(IMyObject<IMyParaInterface> parameter)  {}
```

In this case, MyObject< MyParaClass > will be type-compatible with IMyObject< IMyParaInterface >.

You can read about covariance / contravariance here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance