# Using generics with extensible factories?

Tags: c#, generics

I've reduced my question to an example involving animals.  I want to define a set of interfaces (/abstract classes) that allow anyone to create a factory for a given animal and register it with a central registrar: `AnimalRegistry` keeps track of all the registered `AnimalFactory` objects, which in turn produces and provides a consistent set of functionality for `Animal` objects.

With the way I've written this (code below), I have a pretty simple interface for working with generic animals:

```
        AnimalRegistry registry = new AnimalRegistry();
        registry.Register<ElephantFactory>();
        registry.Register<GiraffeFactory>();

        Animal a1 = registry.GetInstance<ElephantFactory>().Create(new ElephantParams(weight: 1500));
        Animal a2 = registry.GetInstance<GiraffeFactory>().Create(new GiraffeParams(height: 180));

        registry.Serialize(a1);
        registry.Serialize(a2);
```

However, there's something I really don't like about this:

There's nothing at compile-time that stops `ElephantParams` from accidentally getting passed to `registry.GetInstance<GiraffeFactory>().Create(AnimalParams)`.

**How can I write the `AnimalFactory` base class in such a way that ensures at compile-time that only the correct type of `AnimalParams` can be passed while still allowing others to write their own concrete implementations for other animals?**

I could...

- Add explicit methods for `Create(ElephantParams)` and `Create(GiraffeParams)` to their respective classes, but that would require ditching the contract that all base classes have a Create() method.
- Add an additional mapping in `AnimalRegistry` between `AnimalParams` and the appropriate factory and define a new `Create()` method in the registry, but that's not really an elegant solution as the problem is just moved rather than solved.

I suspect the answer lies in more type generics, but it currently escapes me.

AnimalRegistry:

```
public class AnimalRegistry
{
    Dictionary<Type, AnimalFactory> registry = new Dictionary<Type, AnimalFactory>();

    public void Register<T>() where T : AnimalFactory, new()
    {
        AnimalFactory factory = new T();

        registry[typeof(T)] = factory;
        registry[factory.TypeCreated] = factory;
    }

    public T GetInstance<T>() where T : AnimalFactory
    {
        return (T)registry[typeof(T)];
    }

    public AnimalFactory GetInstance(Animal animal)
    {
        return registry[animal.GetType()];
    }

    public string Serialize(Animal animal)
    {
        return GetInstance(animal).Serialize(animal);
    }
}
```

Base classes:

```
public abstract class AnimalFactory
{
    public abstract string SpeciesName { get; }
    public abstract Type TypeCreated { get; }
    public abstract Animal Create(AnimalParams args);
    public abstract string Serialize(Animal animal);
}
public abstract class Animal
{
    public abstract int Size { get; }
}

public abstract class AnimalParams { }
```

Concrete implementations:

Elephant:

```
public class ElephantFactory : AnimalFactory
{
    public override string SpeciesName => "Elephant";

    public override Type TypeCreated => typeof(Elephant);

    public override Animal Create(AnimalParams args)
    {
        if (args is ElephantParams e)
        {
            return new Elephant(e);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Not elephant params");
        }
    }

    public override string Serialize(Animal animal)
    {
        if (animal is Elephant elephant)
        {
            return $"Elephant({elephant.Weight})";
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Not an elephant");
        }
    }
}

public class Elephant : Animal
{
    public int Weight;
    public override int Size => Weight;

    public Elephant(ElephantParams args)
    {
        Weight = args.Weight;
    }
}

public class ElephantParams : AnimalParams
{
    public readonly int Weight;

    public ElephantParams(int weight) => Weight = weight;
}
```

Giraffe:

```
public class GiraffeFactory : AnimalFactory
{
    public override string SpeciesName => "Giraffe";

    public override Type TypeCreated => typeof(Giraffe);

    public override Animal Create(AnimalParams args)
    {
        if (args is GiraffeParams g)
        {
            return new Giraffe(g);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Not giraffe params");
        }
    }

    public override string Serialize(Animal animal)
    {
        if (animal is Giraffe giraffe)
        {
            return $"Giraffe({giraffe.Height})";
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Not a giraffe");
        }
    }
}
public class Giraffe : Animal
{
    public readonly int Height;
    public override int Size => Height;

    public Giraffe(GiraffeParams args)
    {
        Height = args.Height;
    }
}

public class GiraffeParams : AnimalParams
{
    public int Height;

    public GiraffeParams(int height) => Height = height;
}
```

Comment: I think there is a lot of unneeded code, can you explain me what you want to achieve from scratches?

Comment: @Marco What might seem like redundant code at first, actually plays an important role in how the problem should be approached and solved. Ref [To Many Notes](http://www.toomanynotes.com/Amadeus.htm) ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I write the base class `AnimalFactory` in such a way that ensures at compile-time that only the correct type of `AnimalParams` can be passed, while still allowing others to write their own concrete implementations for other animals?

The answer is twofold:

1. Introduce the same generic type parameter in `Params<T>` as in `Factory<T>`, which returns `T` objects.
2. To truly comply with the *Liskov Substitution Principle*, you'll need to further remodel the base classes.

---

1. **Generics**

First, let's have a look at your `AnimalFactory`.

```
public abstract class AnimalFactory
{
    public abstract string SpeciesName { get; }
    public abstract Type TypeCreated { get; }
    public abstract Animal Create(AnimalParams args);
    public abstract string Serialize(Animal animal);
}
```

The `Create` method is an ideal candidate for strongly typed `args`. However, `AnimalParams` is too coarse-grained, preventing the compiler to enforce the correct type.

The `Serialize` method, on the other hand, is fine the way it is. We don't want to narrow down the type of argument. Keeping it as wide as `Animal` gives us the most flexibility.

These conflicting interests raise a question. Are we trying to model too much in the abstract class' interface? Shouldn't providing animals be the factory's sole responsibility? Let's follow the *Interface Segregation Principle* and factor out the `Serialize` method.

Rewriting `AnimalFactory`, clarifying it's intent.

```
public abstract class Factory<T> where T : Animal
{
    public abstract string SpeciesName { get; }
    public abstract Type TypeCreated { get; }
    public abstract T Create(Params<T> args);
}

public interface ISerialize
{
    string Serialize(Animal animal);
}

public abstract class Animal
{
    public abstract int Size { get; }
}

public abstract class Params<T> where T : Animal { }
```

Note the change from `AnimalParams` to `Params<T> where T : Animal`. This is key to providing type safety.

```
public class ElephantParams : Params<Elephant>
{
    public readonly int Weight;

    public ElephantParams(int weight) => Weight = weight;
}
```

Only one descendant of `Params<Elephant>` is allowed, enforced with the cast `(ElephantParams)p`.

```
public class ElephantService : Factory<Elephant>, ISerialize
{
    public override string SpeciesName => "Elephant";

    public override Type TypeCreated => typeof(Elephant);

    public override Elephant Create(Params<Elephant> p)
    {
        return new Elephant((ElephantParams)p);
    }

    public string Serialize(Animal animal)
    {
        if (animal is Elephant elephant)
        {
            return $"Elephant({elephant.Weight})";
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Not an elephant");
        }
    }
}
```

---

2. **Liskov**

You could skip this part, however, the previous sample has something of a code smell.

```
public override Elephant Create(Params<Elephant> p)
{
    return new Elephant((ElephantParams)p);
}
```

It's hard to shake the feeling that we're doing things the other way round. It starts in the abstract base classes.

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public abstract int Size { get; }
}

public abstract class Params<T> where T : Animal { }
```

Where `Params<T>` is no more than a marker interface. The *Liskov Substitution Principle* is based on the fact that an interface should define polymorphic behavior, that all instances implement. Thus, ensuring each call on such an instance can provide a meaningful result, given the functionality is always present.

For the sake of argument, let's make `Animal` the marker interface (which isn't a good idea either).

```
public abstract class Animal { }

public abstract class Params<T> where T : Animal
{
    public abstract int Size { get; }
}
```

This reflects in the following changes.

```
public class Elephant : Animal
{
    public int Weight;

    public Elephant(Params<Elephant> args) => Weight = args.Size;
}

public class ElephantParams : Params<Elephant>
{
    private readonly int weight;

    public ElephantParams(int weight) => this.weight = weight;

    public override int Size => weight;
}
```

Allowing us to resolve the code smell and adhere to the *Liskov Substitution Principle*.

```
public override Elephant Create(Params<Elephant> p)
{
    return new Elephant(p);
}
```

Safe to say this brings quite a change of mind, now the base class designer has to abstract all possible concepts that future developers might need in the `Params<T>` definition. If not, they'll be forced to cast to a specific type within the `Create` method and gracefully handle the case where the type isn't the expected one. Otherwise, the app might still crash if someone injects another derived class (with the same type argument `T` in the base class `Params<T>`).

---

**Registry** types:

- Given `Register` generates services on the fly, we'll need to supply a `TService` type argument that's a concrete class (in our case one with a default constructor), such as `ElephantService`.
- To keep it polymorphic, however, we'll abstract this with `TService : Factory<TAnimal>, ISerialize, new()`.
- As we're using  `Factory<TAnimal>` to indicate our type of factory, we'll need to specify `TAnimal` as well.
- When we retrieve a service, we'll do so by referencing the desired interface, not the concrete class.

The `Serialize` signature is same as before, again, it wouldn't make much sense narrowing the field and giving in on flexibility. As that would require us to specify the derived type of `Animal` before serializing.

```
public class AnimalRegistry
{
    Dictionary<Type, object> registry = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public void Register<TService, TAnimal>()
        where TService : Factory<TAnimal>, ISerialize, new()
        where TAnimal : Animal
    {
        TService service = new TService();

        registry[service.GetType()] = service;
        registry[service.TypeCreated] = service;
    }

    public Factory<TAnimal> GetInstance<TAnimal>()
        where TAnimal : Animal
    {
        return (Factory<TAnimal>)registry[typeof(TAnimal)];
    }

    public string Serialize(Animal animal)
    {
        return ((ISerialize)registry[animal.GetType()]).Serialize(animal);
    }
}
```

Composition root remains much like before, with the exception of `Register`'s second type argument and added type safety.

```
AnimalRegistry registry = new AnimalRegistry();
registry.Register<ElephantService, Elephant>();
registry.Register<GiraffeService, Giraffe>();

Animal a1 = registry.GetInstance<Elephant>().Create(new ElephantParams(weight: 1500));
Animal a2 = registry.GetInstance<Giraffe>().Create(new GiraffeParams(height: 180));
//Doesn't compile
//Animal a3 = registry.GetInstance<Elephant>().Create(new GiraffeParams(height: 180));

registry.Serialize(a1);
registry.Serialize(a2);
```

---

**UPDATE**

> If I wanted to write a GetInstances() method that would return all AnimalFactory instances in the registry, how would I go about typing that method?

You can use reflection to filter types that extend `Factory<T>`.

```
private bool IsFactory(Type type)
{
    return
        type.BaseType.IsGenericType &&
        type.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Factory<>);
}

public List<object> GetInstances()
{
    var factoryTypes = registry.Keys.Where(IsFactory);
    return factoryTypes.Select(key => registry[key]).ToList();
}
```

However,

1. A generic collection (`List<T>`) can only contain elements of the same type
2. `typeof(Factory<Elephant>) != typeof(Factory<Giraffe>)`
3. You can't cast to `Factory<Animal>`, ref [generic variance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528821/generics-and-casting-cannot-cast-inherited-class-to-base-class)

So, the `List<object>` may not prove that useful. As suggested, you could use an auxiliary interface or derive `Factory<T>` from an abstract `Factory`.

Comment: Exactly the kind of solution I was looking for!  The main missing piece for me was that I didn't know C# could do this: `public abstract class Factory<T> where T : Animal` and then `public class ElephantService : Factory<Elephant>`.

Comment: If I wanted to write a `GetInstances()` method that would return _all_ `AnimalFactory` instances in the registry, how would I go about typing that method?  `AnimalFactory<Animal>` doesn't work.  Am I stuck using an auxiliary interface (like you use `ISerialize`) to define that shared behavior?

Comment: @Benjin Good question, see my update on the pitfalls.