# C# casting Action generics

Tags: c#, generics, casting, action

I have my first class like

```
public abstract class A
{
    protected event Action<A> onCompleted;

    public void CompleteExecution()
    {
        // doing something...
        onCompleted?.Invoke(this);
    }
}
```

and another class like

```
public class B : A
{
    private Action<B> _callback;

    public void Initialize(Action<B> callback)
    {
        _callback = callback;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        onCompleted += (Action<A>)callback;
        // doing something specific.
    }
}
```

then I use B with something like:

```
public class Executor
{
    private B _inst;

    public Executor
    {
        _inst = new B();
        _inst.Initialize(Callback);
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        _inst.Execute();
    }

    public void Finalize()
    {
        _inst.CompleteExecution();
    }

    private void Callback(B inst)
    {
        // completed !!!
    }
}
```

I thought I could cast Action if the arguments where related but I am getting an invalid cast exception at

```
onCompleted += (Action<A>)callback;
```

in the Execute method of the B class.

I solved this by replacing the line with

```
onCompleted += _ => callback?.Invoke(this);
```

but I find it very ugly.

Is there a better way for achieving the cast?

Comment: `Action<A>` and `Action<B>` are two completely unrelated types. While `B` is-a `A` , `Action<B>` _is not_-a `Action<A>` and thus they cannot just be casted into one another.

Comment: Instead, you may want to create a separate `EventArgs` type (or interface that both implement).

Comment: Imagine you *could* do that: `Action<A> a = (Action<A>) myBDelegate;`. That would enable us to provide *any arbitrary instance of `A`* to the delegate, not just `B`. So this would also be valid: `a.Invoke(new C())` (assuming `C`also derives from `A`, but *not* from `B`) When your delegate is of type `Action<B>`, it expects an instance of `B`, not an instance of `C`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generics and casting - cannot cast inherited class to base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528821/generics-and-casting-cannot-cast-inherited-class-to-base-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a better way for achieving the cast?

No. `Action<T>` is [contravariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/), meaning you can convert `Action<A>` to `Action<B>`. This works because `B` inherits from `A`, the same reason `void MyMethodA(A a)` can be called with an instance of `B` as the argument.

But it is not *covariant*, so you cannot do the reverse. For the same reason `void MyMethodB(B b)` cannot be called with an instance of `A` as the argument.

If your current workaround works you can just use that. You might also be able to do something with generics, see the [Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). But be warned that this can increase the complexity of your solution. Or you can declare an event with the same name in both classes, and use the [new modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier) to hide the inherited member.